# -supplementalTargetForAction:sender: not called for cancelOperation: key action

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm having an NSSplitViewController with a `-(id)supplementalTargetForAction:(SEL)action sender:(id)sender` to make sure that all child view controllers are part of the responder chain.

For some reason when I press the Escape key, this method is not called for `cancelOperation:` while it is called for the `complete:` action, which is tried after `cancelOperation:`.

If I implement `cancelOperation:` on NSWindow, then it gets called, so it's not found anywhere else in the responder chain.

How can I make sure that `-(id)supplementalTargetForAction:(SEL)action sender:(id)sender` gets called for `cancelOperation:`?

Why does NSResponder skip `-(id)supplementalTargetForAction:(SEL)action sender:(id)sender` for `cancelOperation:` but not for `complete:`?

Comment: Maybe `cancelOperation:` is eaten by one of the subviews. NSTableVIew implements `cancelOperation:`. The key window searches for an implementation of `cancelOperation:`, it doesn't just follow the responder chain.

Comment: If I place a symbolic breakpoint on `cancelOperation:`, it is never hit. It also wouldn't explain that the `complete:` action is tried, as it's tried when `cancelOperation:` isn't found.

Comment: I think it's a bug.